# std::string as a subset of a collection

Tags: c++

Can `std::string` be considered like a concrete implementation of `std::vector<char*>` (saving the differences)? `std::string` looks like a buffer of characters grouped in a typename, with concrete methods that allows you to manipullate characters in a neat and convenient way. But I wanted to know what are beyond those implications, and the differences at *storage level* of the data between the both two.

Comment: You might want to read up on short string optimization.

Comment: you can also have `std::string_view` over `std::vector`. but as always. use a string if you want a string.